# Js FOR loop returning 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

Im trying to add asterisks at the beginning and end of each word but I keep getting undefined at the end of my new string. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
function solution(s) {
var asterisks = "*"
var newString = ""
for(let i = 0; i <= s.length; i++){
    if(s === ""){
        return "*";
    }else{
    newString += asterisks + s[i];} 
}
return newString;
}
```

Comment: for example if were to log solution("star"), I would get "*s*t*a*r*undefined"
But what I want is "*s*t*a*r*"

Answer (score 2):

I think your for loop should be

```
for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
```

Cause in the last time of your for loop, i = s.length.

And s[s.length] = undefined

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is `for(let i = 0; i <= s.length; i++)` the `<=` should just be `<` the undefined is coming from the last "length" character not existing.

You can get around adding the final `*` and the end of the last letter by add this code to the for loop:

```
if (i == (s.length -1)){
    return newString += asterisks;
    }
```

Working example:

```js
function solution(s) {
var asterisks = "*"
var newString = ""
for(let i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    if(s === ""){
        return "*";
    }else{
    newString += asterisks + s[i];} 
    
    if (i == (s.length -1)){
    return newString += asterisks;
    }
}
return newString;
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = solution('hello');
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```